# Merge rows based on row label - pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df which looks like this:

```
      q11__business_booking_channels  q11__leisure_booking_channels
Base                      375.012329                            NaN
Base                             NaN                     374.987669
```

I want to merge on rows, to make the df look like this:

```
      q11__business_booking_channels  q11__leisure_booking_channels
Base                      375.012329                     374.987669
```

My failed attempt:

```
df = df.groupby(df.index)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
df.groupby(df.index).first()

      q11__business_booking_channels  q11__leisure_booking_channels
Base                      375.012329                     374.987669
```

Comment: The two rows were merged into one but the values were '375.012329', '0.0'. I'm guessing the it didnt merge the values?

Comment: no it did, but the data you have is different then the one you posted, it looks like your first non null value is a zero, the purpose of the first function is it takes the first non null value

Comment: Right, makes sense!

Comment: You were right, I replaced the 0 to np.nan and then it worked.